# FastAPI load test failing when verifying JWT token

Tags: python, rest, python-asyncio, fastapi, load-testing

I'm trying to create some endpoints on fastAPI.
I tried load testing from postman but im getting the below error.
it looks like jwt is processed Asynchronously but my understanding is the dependency will be executed first and then the function(endpoint logic) will be executed but i'm not sure how it is processed here.
without jwt dependency load test gives success response for all requests.
but with jwt validation it is failing.

```py
@router.get("/task/{id}") # to fetch a particular task from db
def getTask(id:int,db: Session =Depends(get_db),currentUser: dict = Depends(getCurrentUser)):
    print(currentUser)
    task = db.query(Task).filter(Task.id == id).first()
    if task.owner_id == currentUser.id:
        return(task)
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f'requested task id: {id} not available')
        #return({"message":f'requested task id: {id} not available'})
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl='login')

SECRET_KEY = "kjjuhdsfvjkhdkfvkdsfjvhlidhfvidhhsf"
ALGORITHM = "HS256"
ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES = 300

def createToken(data:dict):
    to_encode = data.copy()
    expire = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes= ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)

    to_encode.update({"exp":expire})
    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(to_encode, SECRET_KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)
    return encoded_jwt

def verifyToken(token:str,credentialException):
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get('userid')
        print(f'the logged in user is {username}')
        if username is None:
            raise credentialException
        return username
    except ExpiredSignatureError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    except JWTError as e:
        print(e)

def getCurrentUser(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme),db : Session =Depends(get_db)):
    credentialException = HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail='not authorized',headers={"WWW-Authenticate":"Bearer"})
    token = verifyToken(token,credentialException)

    currentUser = db.query(User).filter(User.email == token).first()

    return(currentUser)
```

looks like some async issue all my functions are synchronous.

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\anyio\streams\memory.py", line 98, in receive
    return self.receive_nowait()
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\anyio\streams\memory.py", line 93, in receive_nowait
    raise WouldBlock
anyio.WouldBlock

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\base.py", line 78, in call_next
    message = await recv_stream.receive()
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\anyio\streams\memory.py", line 118, in receive
    raise EndOfStream
anyio.EndOfStream

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 428, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 282, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\base.py", line 108, in __call__
    response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next)
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\main.py", line 65, in add_process_time_header
    response = await call_next(request)
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\base.py", line 84, in call_next
    raise app_exc
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\base.py", line 70, in coro
    await self.app(scope, receive_or_disconnect, send_no_error)
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\cors.py", line 83, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
    raise e
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 241, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 169, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\starlette\concurrency.py", line 41, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 33, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread        
    return await future
  File "H:\projects\fastApi-user-login\git code\userLogin\myenv\lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 807, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
```

Comment: Noone can help you of you don't show your code.

Comment: Punctuation is your friend. Without a single comma or period I really don't understand anything you are saying/asking.